RDLC report generation from datatable
 private void btnFrmFeePaymentPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     DataTable dTStudentDetails = new DataTable();            

     DataColumn ReceiptNo = new DataColumn("ReceiptNo", typeof(string));
     DataColumn StudentID = new DataColumn("StudentID", typeof(string));
     DataColumn Name = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string));
     DataColumn Date = new DataColumn("Date", typeof(string));
     DataColumn Session = new DataColumn("Session", typeof(string));
     DataColumn CourseSelected = new DataColumn("CourseSelected", typeof(string));
     DataColumn Total = new DataColumn("Total", typeof(string));
     DataColumn PaymentMode = new DataColumn("PaymentMode", typeof(string));
     DataColumn TotalInWord = new DataColumn("TotalInWord", typeof(string));
     DataColumn CollectedBy = new DataColumn("CollectedBy", typeof(string));

     dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add(ReceiptNo);
     dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add(StudentID);
     dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add(Name);
     dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add(Date);
     dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add(Session);
     dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add(CourseSelected);
     dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add(Total);
     dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add(PaymentMode);
     dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add(TotalInWord);
     dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add(CollectedBy);

     DataRow drow1 = dTStudentDetails.NewRow();
     dTStudentDetails.Rows.Add(drow1);

     dTStudentDetails.Rows[0][ReceiptNo] = studentDetails.receptno;
     dTStudentDetails.Rows[0][StudentID] = studentDetails.student_id;
     dTStudentDetails.Rows[0][Name] = studentDetails.firstname + " " + studentDetails.middelname + " " + studentDetails.lastname;
     dTStudentDetails.Rows[0][Date] = dTPickerFrmFeePaymentDate.Text.ToString();
     dTStudentDetails.Rows[0][Session] = studentDetails.sessionID;
     dTStudentDetails.Rows[0][CourseSelected] = studentDetails.coursename;
     dTStudentDetails.Rows[0][Total] = studentDetails.Total;
     dTStudentDetails.Rows[0][PaymentMode] = studentDetails.PaymentType;
     dTStudentDetails.Rows[0][TotalInWord] = studentDetails.TotalinWord;
     dTStudentDetails.Rows[0][CollectedBy] = studentDetails.Collectedby;

     DataTable dTPayDetails = new DataTable();

     DataColumn TransactionID = new DataColumn("TransactionID", typeof(string));
     DataColumn Particular = new DataColumn("Particular", typeof(string));
     DataColumn TypeOfPayment = new DataColumn("TypeOfPayment", typeof(string));
     DataColumn Amount = new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(string));

     dTPayDetails.Columns.Add(TransactionID);
     dTPayDetails.Columns.Add(Particular);
     dTPayDetails.Columns.Add(TypeOfPayment);
     dTPayDetails.Columns.Add(Amount);

     for (int i = 0; i < studentDetails.TransNo.Count; i++)
     {
         DataRow drow2 = dTPayDetails.NewRow();
         dTPayDetails.Rows.Add(drow2);
         dTPayDetails.Rows[i][TransactionID] = studentDetails.TransNo[i].ToString();
         dTPayDetails.Rows[i][Particular] = studentDetails.Parti[i].ToString();
         dTPayDetails.Rows[i][TypeOfPayment] = studentDetails.Installment[i].ToString();
         dTPayDetails.Rows[i][Amount] = studentDetails.Amount[i].ToString();
     }

     reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"./report/ReportFeePayment.rdlc";            

     DataSet1 dataSet1 = new DataSet1();
     DataSet2 dataSet2 = new DataSet2();

     dataSet1.Tables.Add(dTStudentDetails.TableName);
     dataSet2.Tables.Add(dTPayDetails.TableName);

     ReportDataSource rds1 = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dataSet1.Tables);
     ReportDataSource rds2 = new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", dataSet2.Tables);

     this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
     this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds1);
     this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds2);

     this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

     this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

 }

I am new with RDLC report, I have a form Fee details which is update by user and all details of payment is feed in that, when user press save this data is saving to the database and this part is completed, now i want to print this receipt so i transfre this data to a class object and with that class object the data is transfred to data table, during debuging i am able to see that data table is loaded with the feed data.
Now i created 2 data sets with below data structure


and transfaring the data table to dataset and then to report veiwer, now this code is runing without any error and report is also updating but it is not showing any data.
If is use SQL quearies and add the dataAdaptor then is it going through and data is showing but i don't want to access the database again as all data is available with me and i can print it without furthe database access.

So finally I got the solution and now the report is generating.
{
DataTable dTStudentDetails = new DataTable();            

dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add("ReceiptNo", typeof(string));
dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add("StudentID", typeof(string));
dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add("Session", typeof(string));
dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add("CourseSelected", typeof(string));
dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(string));
dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add("PaymentMode", typeof(string));
dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add("TotalInWord", typeof(string));
dTStudentDetails.Columns.Add("CollectedBy", typeof(string));

DataRow drow1 = dTStudentDetails.NewRow();
dTStudentDetails.Rows.Add(drow1);

dTStudentDetails.Rows[0]["ReceiptNo"] = studentDetails.receptno;
dTStudentDetails.Rows[0]["StudentID"] = studentDetails.student_id;
dTStudentDetails.Rows[0]["Name"] = studentDetails.firstname + " " + studentDetails.middelname + " " + studentDetails.lastname;
dTStudentDetails.Rows[0]["Date"] = dTPickerFrmFeePaymentDate.Text.ToString();
dTStudentDetails.Rows[0]["Session"] = studentDetails.sessionID;
dTStudentDetails.Rows[0]["CourseSelected"] = studentDetails.coursename;
dTStudentDetails.Rows[0]["Total"] = studentDetails.Total;
dTStudentDetails.Rows[0]["PaymentMode"] = studentDetails.PaymentType;
dTStudentDetails.Rows[0]["TotalInWord"] = studentDetails.TotalinWord;
dTStudentDetails.Rows[0]["CollectedBy"] = studentDetails.Collectedby;

DataTable dTPayDetails = new DataTable();

dTPayDetails.Columns.Add("TransactionID", typeof(string));
dTPayDetails.Columns.Add("Particular", typeof(string));
dTPayDetails.Columns.Add("TypeOfPayment", typeof(string));
dTPayDetails.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(string));

for (int i = 0; i < studentDetails.TransNo.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow drow2 = dTPayDetails.NewRow();
    dTPayDetails.Rows.Add(drow2);
    dTPayDetails.Rows[i]["TransactionID"] = studentDetails.TransNo[i].ToString();
    dTPayDetails.Rows[i]["Particular"] = studentDetails.Parti[i].ToString();
    dTPayDetails.Rows[i]["TypeOfPayment"] = studentDetails.Installment[i].ToString();
    dTPayDetails.Rows[i]["Amount"] = studentDetails.Amount[i].ToString();
}

reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"./report/ReportFeePayment.rdlc";            

ReportDataSource rds1 = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dTStudentDetails);
ReportDataSource rds2 = new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", dTPayDetails);

MessageBox.Show(dTStudentDetails.TableName.ToString() + dTPayDetails.TableName.ToString());

this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds1);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds2);

this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

}
After checking each step I found that was using the Dataset without any reason, I just loaded the data to Datatable and then passed it to the report viewer, checked all fields and dataset spellings and when I ran it it started generating reports with values passed to it.
